# Terraform - Azure - Virtual Network - Subnets output shuffle

Tags: azure, terraform

We are using Terraform CLI on Azure, We have code for each subscription which create default Storage accounts, keyvault, VNet with subnet etc.  Then we get the output of these services. In the output we also have info related to the VNET Subnets. We had less than 10 subnets before and we created VMs by giving reference of that output of the subnet. After adding more subnets in the same code we observed that after creating more subnets the output of the VNet->subnets has been readjusted/shuffled as shown below:

Changes to Outputs:

```
  ~ msdn_eastus_aks01   = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_aks01" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_webapp"
  ~ msdn_eastus_apimgt  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_apimgt" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_utility"
  ~ msdn_eastus_app     = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_app" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_int_web"
  ~ msdn_eastus_appgw   = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_appgw" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_apimgt"
  ~ msdn_eastus_db      = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_db" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_app"
  ~ msdn_eastus_int_web = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_int_web" -> (known after apply)
  ~ msdn_eastus_utility = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_utility" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_db"
  ~ msdn_eastus_webapp  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_webapp" -> "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf/resourceGroups/msdn-eastus-test-subdefault/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-eastus-test-msdn/subnets/msdn_eastus_appgw"
```

So if we rerun the code of same VMs the referred subnet got changed so the SAME VM is getting the new ip from the different subnet as shown above

Comment: Can you share the piece of terraform code you are using to define the vnet and subnet?

Comment: Sure, but my best guess is that problem is with the output of the VNet Module

output "vnet_ids" {
  value = [for x in azurerm_virtual_network.vnet : x.id]
}

output "vnet_names" {
  value = [for x in azurerm_virtual_network.vnet : x.name]
}

output "vnet_rg_name" {
  value = [for x in azurerm_virtual_network.vnet : x.resource_group_name]
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = [for x in azurerm_subnet.subnet : x.id]
}

Comment: vnets = {
    vnet0 = {
      name          = local.vnet0_name
      address_space = [var.vnet0_cidr]
      dns_servers   = var.vnet0_dns_servers
    }
  }

Comment: This is subnet part

  subnets = {
    subnet1 = {
      vnet_key          = "vnet0"
      name              = "${var.subscription}_${var.location_pri}_ext_web"
      address_prefix    = [replace(var.vnet0_cidr, ".0.0/17", ".1.0/24")]
      rt_key            = "rt0"
      service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.KeyVault"]
      ple_enable        = false
      pls_enable        = false
    }

Comment: Would be helpful to have a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Code in comment is kind of hard to read, but my guess is that the way you are defining the subnets have maybe an unset property that makes terraform build the resources in an indeterministic way on each run

Comment: There was limit of characters so I break them at best possible, I can walk you through by screen sharing if you want to

Comment: No need for that. You can just add it in your question, so anyone else can help you if I can't =)